# Как поменять значение у булевой переменной

Tags: c++, c

Типо нажимаю кнопку A латиницей

```
case Qt::Key_A:
    if(_myTexpr.substrate == true || _myTexpr.substrate == false)
        setSubstrate(true);
    else
        setSubstrate(false);
```

почему-то не меняет false на true

Comment: `setSubstrate(!_myTexpr.substrate);` вместо ваших if else.

Comment: @ori офрмляйте ответ :3 приму :3 как верное решение

Comment: к тому же условие `(_myTexpr.substrate == true || _myTexpr.substrate == false)` в обычных условиях будет всегда истинно.

Comment: Ну, вы же написали по сути (см. закон исключенного третьего) `setSubstrate(true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хоть ответ от автора есть, но всё же предложу более изящный способ через унарное отрицание:

```cpp
case Qt::Key_A:
    setSubstrate(!_myTexpr.substrate); // ! перед переменной превратит True в False и наоборот
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. Уберем все что вы написали в условных операторах, заменим одним выражением отрицания:

```
...

case Qt::Key_A: {
    setSubstrate(!_myTexpr.substrate);
} break;

...
```

2. Используем тернарное ввыражение:

```
...

case Qt::Key_A: {
    setSubstrate(_myTexpr.substrate ? false : true);
} break;

...
```

3. Просто исправим ошибку в вашем коде, там где вы написали выражение, которое всегда после компиляции будет оптимизировано таким образом, что оно просто будет выброшено т.к. не меняется ничего ни при каких условий и проверка становится бесполезной:

```
...

case Qt::Key_A: {
    /* Сравнение можно опустить до if (_myTexpr.substrate) */
    if (true == _myTexpr.substrate) {
        setSubstrate(false);
    } else {
        setSubstrate(true);
    }
} break;
...
```

---

Оффтопик:

Сравнивайте константы с переменными, таким образом вы избавите себя от проблем которые иногда получаются в случае когда вы вместо сравнения вызываете оператор присваивания:

```
case Qt::Key_A: {
    /** Случайно не поставили второе равно
     *  Ошибки во время компиляции не будет
     *  Такой код приводит к неопределенному поведению
     **/
    if (_myTexpr.substrate = true) {
        setSubstrate(true);
    } else {
        setSubstrate(false);
    }
} break;
```

Ниже код никогда не скомпилируется если левая часть выражения константа времени компиляции:

```
case Qt::Key_A: {
    if (true = _myTexpr.substrate) {
        setSubstrate(true);
    } else {
        setSubstrate(false);
    }
} break;
```

P.S. Не будем говорить про `re-define`.

Comment: я думаю, что уже настало время перестать писать `true = _myTexpr.substrate`. Просто включите у компилятора отображение ворнингов. Я понимаю, что трехзвездочные программисты привыкли писать в йодастайле, но зачем коробить себя?

Comment: Ну про булевые значения понятно, я так, отсебятины добавил как оффтоп, речь обо всех присваиваниях констант : )

Comment: как по мне, то йода стайл не нужно использовать. он страшен и печален.

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался

```
case Qt::Key_A:
    if(_myTexpr.substrate == true)
        setSubstrate(false);
    else
        setSubstrate(true);
```

вот так заработало

Comment: ` == true` можно удалить. Оно не нужно

Comment: @KoVadim вау работает , но это не нарушает логику "человеческого" мышления ??? Не теряется ли при этом удобочитаемость кода ??

Comment: нет, ничего не нарушает. если substrate имеет тип bool, то все абсолютно ожидаемо для обычных разработчиков на большинстве языков.